# Unrecognized name: BigQuery Employee

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I keep getting Unrecognized name for the following, please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGuZn.png)

I was following the Inner Join tutorial and keep getting the unrecognized name. i followed as well the aliases. it seems like i am ding something wrong but dont know what.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your tables as e or d when you join them.  Something like this:

```
select
e.name as name,
e.role as role,
d.name as department
from
`db1` AS e -- <-----
inner join
`db2` as d -- <-----
on e.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try once by putting alias name e for employee and d for department in below statement in employee and department:

Example: employee e Department d